# is there a way of amplifying the sound of flash videos beyond their sound bar?

Tags: video, audio, flash

Even when I put both my laptop's volume and the flash player's volume to the maximum, sound is still weak. Is there a way to increase it (e.g., like in xbmc)?

Comment: Make sure that the sound is at 100% on the Operating System level (for instance on the bottom right in Windows, check the speaker icon to make sure that the sound is turned up all the way)

Comment: By default I believe the setVolume is set to 100. Are you sure, the source file isn't fainted from the beginning?

Comment: Everything is set to maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some sound chips have an extra utility to boost the volume even more, if yours has it you will find the utility on the tray bar or on the control panel. Notice that i'm not talking about the little speaker but OTHER utility on the tray bar, or you might need to find it on the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running the latest Realtek HD driver on a Windows 8 PC. This should be standard across Windows PCs with the latest updates. To expand on Bill's answer above, I found that if you click on volume icon next to your clock, and go to the volume mixer>"applications system sounds">playback>advanced you can turn the volume up to 24 bit 192000 Hz studio quality. It's still a bit quiet on some improperly encoded videos but increases audibility exponentially.